# Upgrading Fedora on Amazon to 12 but getting libssl.so.* & libcrypto.so.* are missing

Tags: amazon-ec2, fedora

I am upgrading to Fedora 12 on a Amazon EC2 using help here:
http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/894/fedora-12-bootable-root-ebs-on-ec2/

I managed to do a 64 bit instance OK, however facing some problems with a standard one.

On the final bit of the install from 11 to 12 I am getting an error:

```
 Error: Missing Dependency: libcrypto.so.8 is needed by package httpd-tools-2.2.1.5-1.fc11.1.i586 (installed)
 Error: Missing Dependency: libssl.so.8 is needed by package httpd-tools-2.2.1.5-1.fc11.1.i586 (installed)
```

This is referenced in the comments from the link above but all it says is:

> Q: Apache failed, or libssl.so.* & libcrypto.so.* are missing
>
> A: These versions are mssing the symlinks they require. Easy fix, go symlink them to the newest versions in /lib

However I am afraid I don't know how to do this. If it is any help I tried running the command `locate libssl.so` and got:

```
 /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8b
 /lib/libssl.so.6
```

Comment: Linking won't help. And upgrading from two versions earlier is rarely sane.

Comment: It upgrades in turn, ie 9>10>11>12, is that still bad?

Comment: It can be, if you have no experience dealing with RPM packages. Best to do a fresh install if you haven't.

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes almost certainly too late to help the original poster, but perhaps it will help someone else. The problem is that that howto is plain wrong.

To upgrade Fedora online using yum, follow [Fedora's guide](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum) for doing so (if you like living dangerously). The process goes generally like this:

- `yum update` to update the current version of Fedora
- `yum clean all`
- `yum --releasever=<new_version_number> distro-sync`

Each release has several notes of things that may go wrong or that need to be done specific to that release; so be sure to check those carefully. In particular, Fedora 17 made a [major change to the filesystem layout](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/UsrMove) and there is a special process for dealing with that.

As a general rule, when using this method, one must update from one Fedora version to the next in sequence, not skipping any versions. This makes it critical that you update at least once per year, as Fedora has a very short 13-month lifecycle, and at EOL, mirrors may begin dropping old repositories.

If you need to update from a version of Fedora more than two release numbers behind, therefore, you must upgrade using the installation DVD/USB stick. For instance, today Fedora 17 is current and Fedora 16 is maintained. Therefore you can use the `yum` process to update from Fedora 15, but anything older will require upgrading using the installation media since the online mirrors will likely be long gone.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with EC2 so I am not sure if thre are any diferences between installing an OS on ec2 and a normal host or not, but if this was regular fedora on normal hardware or a regular household VM I'd just try:

```
yum install libcrypto.so.8
yum install libssl.so.8
```

Comment: If I try that I get `No package libcrypto.so.8 avaiable`

Playing with a new instance I have found if I uninstall httpd it appears to let me upgrade, but I'm worried I'm just painting over a crack!

Comment: It's not such a big deal to uninstall httpd-tools if you decide you don't need it.